# Get dataTextField from SelectList in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dropdown, http-get, selectlist

I have a dropdown list that I populated with data using SelectList. I am passing the data from my dropdown to my second page (NewPage). My goal is to get the third parameter (FirstName) from the SelectList in my Controller.

View

```
<select name="dropdown1" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.message, "ID", "FirstName"))"></select>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult NewPage(string dropdown1)
        {
            string firstName = Request.Form["dropdown1"];
            int intID = Convert.ToInt32(dropdown1);
            List<PersonModel> data = new List<PersonModel>()
            {
                new PersonModel()
                {
                    ID = intID,
                    FirstName = firstName
                }
            };
            TempData["Data"] = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            return RedirectToAction("NewPage", "NewPage");
        }
```

The string variable firstName in my controller is null. And I get an error that the content-type is not valid. I normally use Request.Form[""] to get the text from a field, but it does not seem to work in this case because this is a select and not an input box. Any suggestions on how I can get the text from my select box/the 3rd parameter from the SelectList? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options

If you are performing a POST then setting the select NAME attribute to name='dropdown1' it should bind the selected value.

If your view model has a property of the same name you can use asp-for. Here is a select control that I use to post back a change in how data is aggregated. Note that the date from/to controls will bind using their asp-for attribute values

```
<select class="form-control" asp-for="Aggregation"
        asp-area="Management"
        asp-controller="Visits"
        asp-action="Index"
        asp-route-sortcolumn="@Model.SortColumn"
        asp-route-sortorder="@(Model.SortDirection)"
        onchange="$('form').submit();">


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string aggregation, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, string sortColumn = "VisitDate", SortOrder sortOrder = SortOrder.Descending)
    {
        return View(await GetSiteVisitsViewModel(aggregation, dateFrom, dateTo, sortColumn, sortOrder));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> And I get an error that the content-type is not valid.

You have this problem because the action is a Get request,the parameter passed is in the form of querystring, so

```
string firstName = Request.Form["dropdown1"];
```

should be changed to

```
string firstName =Request.Query["FirstName"];
```

And then use Ajax to get both ID and firstName in View, the following is my demo, hope it can help you:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult DropList()
        {
            ViewBag.message = new List<PersonModel>()
            {
                new PersonModel(){ ID=1,FirstName="AA"},
                new PersonModel(){ ID=2,FirstName="BB"},
                new PersonModel(){ ID=3,FirstName="CC"},
            };
                return View();
        }


        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IActionResult NewPage(string dropdown1)
        {
            string firstName =Request.Query["FirstName"];
            int intID = Convert.ToInt32(dropdown1);
            List<PersonModel> data = new List<PersonModel>()
            {
                new PersonModel()
                {
                    ID = intID,
                    FirstName = firstName
                }
            };
            TempData["Data"] = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
            return RedirectToAction("NewPage", "NewPage");
        }
```

Model:

```
public class PersonModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="NewPage" method="get">
   <select name="dropdown1" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.message, "ID", "FirstName"))"></select>
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var text = $("select[name=dropdown1] option:selected").text();
                var val = $("select[name=dropdown1] option:selected").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Get',
                    url: '/NewPage?dropdown1=' + val + "&firstName=" + text,
                });
            })
        });

    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]